# Key doesn't match a known application

Tags: support, api-v2

I'm running into a really weird issue and I would appreciate any guidance on what I'm doing wrong. So I recently applied for an API key here on Stack Exchange and it went through fine. So let's say (for example) I received the following API key:

```
abc3efghijk1mnop2rstuv
```

So using this key, I'm attempting to run a simple query like:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/info?key=abc3efghijk1mnop2rstuv&site=stackoverflow
```

And I get the message:

```
{
    "error_id": 400,
    "error_name": "bad_parameter",
    "error_message": "`key` doesn't match a known application"
}
```

Am I using the API key correctly?

Note that I didn't want to post the *real* API key here for obvious reasons but if need be I can provide it.

Comment: I am encountering the same problem currently... And my authentification key is a 2.0 API key...

    https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?site=stackoverflow&key=%2206KzS*pWtt4j88or54fjzQ%28%28%22&tag=%22C%22&fromdate=1230768000&todate=1230768000 </code>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tim Stone pointed out that I was trying to use a 1.1 key with the 2.0 API, which of course doesn't work.

I've registered for a [2.0 API key](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth) and everything is sorted out now.

Comment: note, this can also occur if you accidentally mix up your secret and key (or supply invalid key in general)

Comment: I am encountering the same problem currently... And the answer provided here doesn't seem to help...

My authentification key is a 2.0 API key...  I have copied it from my application page (http://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/view).

But the request still gives an error:

    https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?site=stackoverflow&key=%22V*9VFD9SysYMOxJEoKLj2Q%28%28%22&tag=%22C%22&fromdate=1230768000&todate=1230768000

Comment: same here... after several years :(